# how to get the first category id in rails find method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following in my controller

```
@posts = Post.where(category_id: params[:id]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20).to_a
```

I need to get the category id so i tried

```
@category = @posts.category_id.first
```

And i used it in view hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" value="<%= @category %>" />
```

How do i get the id in my hidden field and getting the error as

> undefined method `category_id'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@posts` is an array. You cannot invoke a `Post` method on an array of posts. You need to pick one post from the array on which to invoke the method. To get the first one, you'd use `@posts[0]` or `@posts.first`. Now that you have a post, you can ask for its category_id:

```
@category = @posts.first.category_id
```

That said, you already have that same value at `params[:id]`, so why not use that?

Comment: I was just wondering the same about why not using params[:id].